# How can I conditionally check a property in the .aspx file inside EpiServer:MenuList?

Tags: asp.net, episerver

I'm building a menu in EpiServer where I only want to include items that is of a certain pagetype. If the repeated item has a pagetype that equals "X" then print it out, else don't do nothing.

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <li>
    <span class="menu-level-1">
      <%# Container.CurrentPage.PageTypeName == "NameOfPageType" ? "Something": "" %>                       
      <span class="menu-divider"></span>
    </span>
 ...
 ..
 .
```

I want to print out every (who meets the criteria) items pagename, i.e:

```
<EPiServer:Property PropertyName="PageName" runat="server">
```

What is the correct syntax for exceuting code rather than printing out "Something"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with either:

```
<%# Container.CurrentPage.PageTypeName == "NameOfPageType" ? Container.CurrentPage.PageName : "" %>
```

or wrap your Property control with a standard ASP.NET PlaceHolder control:

```
<span class="menu-level-1">
  <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible=<%# Container.CurrentPage.PageTypeName == "NameOfPageType" %> >
        <EPiServer:Property PropertyName="PageName" runat="server" />
      </asp:PlaceHolder>
      <span class="menu-divider"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: This was excactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the Filter event from the underlying [`PageTreeData` control](http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms6.1/html/T_EPiServer_Web_WebControls_PageTreeData.htm).

Try something like this

```
yourMenulistControl.Filter += 
       (o, args) => new FilterCompareTo("PageTypeName", "YOURPAGETYPENAME")
                        .Filter(args.Pages);
```